# Original source for Maharil endorsing tunes as "MiSinai"?

Tags: minhag, history, music

[Cantor Goffin describes](http://download.yutorah.org/2012/1053/Rosh_Hashanah_To-Go_-_5769_Cantor_Sherwood_Goffin.pdf) how over 500 years ago, Maharil endorsed several cantorial tunes as "MiSinai" -- "so authoritative it's as if they go back to Sinai" -- for use in the prayers.

What's the primary source on this? Do we have published musical notation of his?

Comment: Are you looking for the Maharil inside, the official musical notation for the Misinai tunes, or an official list of which tunes are Misinai?

Comment: Ideally, "the Maharil inside."

Comment: Shalom, the Rama quotes a Maharil along these lines in OC 619:1 and Darkei Moshe there, but I can't seem to find it in the Maharil itself.

Comment: See this (it doesn't mention anything about the tunes being from Sinai,. though): http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29089&hilite=30b083b2-8bd6-4f66-a2b8-4c774b05fc85&st=%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99&pgnum=23

Comment: @DoubleAA That sounds like worthy material for an answer, though a better answer may someday supersede it.

Comment: @ba can you derive information from that source to write an answer?

Comment: @GershonGold can you derive information from those sources to write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

[Otzar Dinim U'Minhagim - page 254 Nigunim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37057&st=&pgnum=265&hilite=) and then on [page 255](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37057&st=&pgnum=266) says that most of these songs are from the Maharal M'Prag.

[Rabbi Shmuel Pinchas Gelbard](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=80237) attributes them to the Maharil.

See also [Maharil Uzemano](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29089&st=&pgnum=23) that attributes these songs to the Maharil. (Thanks b a)

Perhaps Otzar Dinim U'minhagim meant to say Maharil rather than Maharal M'Prag?